# Dropdown won't work in drupal

Tags: php, css, drupal, menu, ckeditor

I'm redoing a website for a society at my Uni. Heres my progress: [www.linclund.com/Newlund.com](http://www.linclund.com/Newlund.com).

I'm very new to Drupal and Ckeditor and have done the majority of the work in CSS and html thus far. 
My plan now is to get a decent dropdown menu, i installed the nice menu module and got it to be activated with all the scripts and styles, but it still won't respond as a dropdown.

This is what i'm looking at on the main page.php.

```
<?php if (isset($primary_links)) : ?>
<div class="pr-menu"><?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links')) ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything else seems to be normal, what do you have to do to get the dropdown functions of the  menu activated? Could it be some script or style thats conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the main menu links and set all links with children as expanded by default. Check the checkbox "**Show as expanded**" to enable this option.

But, the code you provide prints a specific menu (primary links) with a specific structure. You should better install the [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module and place the menu block under a region of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the nice menu block in a region. On nicemenu block's configuration page, you need to select the 'Menu' you want to use with nicemenu. Otherwise try supuerfish menu! I will offer what you want!